# Display snackbar in any activity

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have four activities in my android app.

MainActivity-->ListFilesActivity-->DisplayFileActivity-->EditFileActivity.

My application is connected to a server, the maximum time allowed to use the application is 30 Min ( this value can change, it depends of server policy).

The server send a timeout remainder to the client in the 20 ( **`you have 10 min left`** )and 25( **`you have 5min left`**) minutes after user login.

it's working fine if the user is in the MainActivity at the receiving moment( i receive the message and i display a snackbar with server message).

More details :

**(I have a java class Listener that listen to message from server, when it receives a message, it calls MainActivity function and display the snackbar)**

using this way is not correct, because i can call only one activity to display snackbar.

My problem is how to use a global snackbar, so the application will display the snackber in any activity, so the user can always see the displayed message.

Is it possible to do it with a snackbar( or is better to use another info displayer type)?

if not, do you have any idea how to handle it ?

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to make a global `Method` that is accessible in the other four classes...

```
public void globalSnackbar(String text) {
  View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  if (rootView != null) {
    Snackbar.make(rootView, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  }
}
```

and then call `globalSnackbar` in other activities.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display the same Snackbar across multiple activities or fragments because a Snackbar is tightly coupled to the view that it is initiated in. So whenever you leave that view the Snackbar will disappear.

I would recommend using a Toast message instead which will display on different activities, fragments and views and does not disappear during the navigation process.

Comment: i will try working with other propositions(snackbar), if not working, i will accept your answer, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The snackbar depends on a View. You could create a BaseActivity class and make all your activities inherits from it, then you can show the snackbar from any activity with a method like this:

```
protected void showSnackbar(View view, String text) {
  if(view != null) {
    Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHOW).show(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it and let you know

Comment: I think i should share more information with you, i will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an activity and four fragments.

Comment: Good idea, but this is not possible in my case. thank you

Comment: If you are using a ViewModel to show the snackbar, you could share your ViewModel between all the activities and observe the LiveData to show it.

Comment: can you give me more details please ?

Comment: You can create a ViewModel with a LiveData that observes another LiveData in your listener class.  All activities must observed the livedata.  When your listener class received the data, must initialize the LiveData that is observed from ViewModel LiveData and the activity can be show the snackbar.

Comment: @Manuel Mato, A fragment is a view by itself, and the snackbar will disappear when navigating from activity to fragment and from fragment to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way.

i declared two  global static boolean values,

```
boolean msgFiveMinReceived = false; // default
boolean msgTenMinReceived = false; // default
```

when my Listener class receive a server message ( for example 10 min left)

```
msgTenMinReceived = true;
```

in each Activity , i run a thread function that check the boolean values

```
    Public void checkMessage() {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i++ < 100000) {
                        try {
if(msgTenMinReceived ) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

     // display snackbar

    }
        // set msgTen to false                           
    }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
```